# Missing delete attachments button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-form, attachments, delete

I have Calendar wherein the EditForm `ListFormWebPart` the button needed to delete an attachment is missing on some (almost all) attachments.

I'm `Admin` so I don't think the problem is regarding permissions.

[image]

Any ideas or hints to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a normal behavior with the `recurrence events` when you try to edit **a specific one event** in the Event series !

So you should be aware of the following :

1. If the file attached for **a specific event level** . you can get the `delete link` for only the related files that attached directly for this event when editing this specific event.
2. If the file attached for the **Even series level**,you can't get the `deleted link` when you try to edit **a specific one event** belong to the entire Event series !

So this is the main reason for why you get a `delete link` for specific files.

**To be more clear :**

The following image , show two files

- `review.txt` (doesn't have a delete link)
- `task view.png` (has a delete link)

[image]

- You will note that `review.txt` file doesn't have a `delete link` because it's attached to `the Even series level`, you try to edit **a specific event** within this `entire Event series` ,
- Meanwhile, the file `task view.png` has `delete link` because it's directly attached to this event ,

So to get the `delete link` for `review.txt` file  , you should edit the `entire series`. by following the mentioned steps below :

- Click on any event at your recurrence Event.
- From the above ribbon > Click View Event.
- After the Event has been shown > from the above ribbon > click on Edit Series.
  [image]
- Now you should find `Delete Attachment` link. for all files that attached to the entire series , not for a specific link.

[image]

**Note :** when you edit the entire series you can delete only the files that attached directly to the entire series , where the attached file `task view.png` for a specific event within the entire series will not be shown by default.

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation